# Inner join in rails with multiple condition

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

How to do inner join with multiple condition in rails?

```
Plan.joins <<-SQL
  inner join config_plans on config_plans.plan_id = #{table_name}.id 
  and config_plans.plan_type = #{plan_type}"
SQL
```

plan_type = "VisionPlan"
table_name = "vision_plans"

Error i am getting => column "visionplan" does not exist

Comment: What is the issue you got in this current one?

Comment: please add the whole error message/